# In a Windows Phone app which approach is better?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In an WP app which approach is better.

1. From the .xaml page, call a method of another class (pass the delegate of a .xaml.cs callback Method ) which makes some request to server , receives data and when requests complete calls the .xaml.cs page method. and in call back method we get data and bind the data with a control (ListBox).
2. Bind the List box with an ObservableCollection object of MainViewModel class. and change the bounded object from the MainViewModel. All the calls to requests to server are made in MainViewModel class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I vote for the option 2. Event the project templates (Eg. Databound application template for Windows Phone 7) gives you the `MainViewModel` and binds a `Listbox` to an `ObservableCollection` in that class.

The `MVVC` approach gives you a lot more flexibility, your UI is totally separated from the logic. ALl your UI needs to know is that it is bound to an `ObservableCollection` and it doesn't need to know how that collection is filled.

Comment: Agreed, keeping as much code out of the .xaml.cs allows you to write automated tests for it individually (assuming you control access to it's dependencies, like web requests)

Comment: Thanks, but the with first approach your UI also remains totally separated from the logic, and when the execution controls comes back to the call back method in xaml.cs i can make some other changes in the UI like show/hide some controls. and with the second approach if the application is large your MainViewModel class can be of thousands lines, and difficult to manage.

Comment: You're not supposed to keep all tha Applications logic in one MainViewModel, you have many ViewModels that have logic for different parts of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the second approach which allows you to create loosely-coupled applications. The big advantages of such applications are:

- **separation of concerns**: different subsystems/layers are independent
- **unit testing** is simple
- **refactoring** is easier
- increase ability to **code reuse**
- **...**

Regarding WP7, you can read my article which shows how to code using this approach:
[a framework for building of WP7 application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/PhoneCoreFramework.aspx)